# Combinatorics In how many ways can $5$ identical pieces be placed on square of $8-8$ board so that $4$ of them form corners of rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Combinatorics

In how many ways can $5$ identical pieces be placed on square of $8-8$ board so that $4$ of them form corners of rectangle

Anyone?
My main doubt is how to include rectangles formed diagonally

Also i need the same for $6$ pieces

Comment: what is a rectangle formed diagonally?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh suppose the pieces placed diagonally forms rectangle

Comment: A computer search gives $1192$ ways to make rectangles with $4$ pieces. For each of these there are $60$ places to put an extra piece, so the answer for $5$ pieces is $60 \cdot 1192 = 71,520$.

Comment: Yes, the diagonals are included. The non-diagonal part of the $1192$ is ${\binom 8 2 }^2 = 784$.

Comment: @Jens  yep but how it comes, any guess do u have any approach

Comment: You can calculate the number of diagonals in a similar way to how the $784$ was calculated, if you find all lines with slope $1$ and $-1$, slope $0.5$ and $-2$, etc but it is tedious to do. So I just made a program which ran through all possibilities. FYI the number of diagonals for each possible slope is the following: $(1/1):196, (1/2):118, (1/3):44, (1/4):18, (1/5):8, (1/6):2, (2/3):18, (2/5):2, (3/4):2$